# Set CoC nodejs path dynamically

Tags: vimscript, plugin-coc

Currently for [CoC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) I am setting the nodejs path like this:

```
let g:coc_node_path = '/usr/local/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node'
```

But I want this variable to be set to the output of `which node`. How can I do this? The CoC config guide does not mention this, and it's my understanding that this is a vim script specific feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I should have searched the internet more before I asked this question. I was able to accomplish what I needed using the `system` function.

So here I needed to do:

```
let g:coc_node_path = substitute(system('which node'), '\n', '', '')
```

The `substitute` is necessary because we need to get rid of the new line at the end of the output, otherwise the path is invalid.

Comment: If your vim is new enough it should have trim()

Comment: And if it's old, you could always `which node | tr -d "\n"`

Comment: "`system` command would slow down your vim on startup **significantly**" https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/856#issuecomment-641018691